# Как отправить url страницы, с которой заполнена форма?

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть форма, данные из которой отдаются методом POST php скрипту.
Как также передать и url страницы с формой?

Возможно ли это?

Я думаю примерно так надо делать:

1. Взять javascript'om адрес страницы (как?)
2. Присвоить это значение хидден инпуту
3. Передать на сервер

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: а в массиве $_SERVER нету?

Comment: Не стоит отправлять урл с клиента на сервер, его можно будет очень легко подделать. Никогда не доверяйте данным, которые приходят на сервер. Используйте HTTP_REFERER как вам уже ответили

Comment: HTTP_REFERER так же передается с клиентской стороны :) И совсем не гарантированно что он вообще будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var url = window.location

Answer (score 3):

Добавить в форму:

```
<input type="hidden" name="page_url" value="<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" />
```

Answer (score 2):

посмотрите, может подойдет [HTTP_REFERER](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php) парметр суперглобального $_SERVER

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте вот так:

```
$(function() {
   var page_link = window.location;
   $('input[text]:hidden').val(page_link);
});
```

Comment: Оригинально решение, чдля того что-бы отправить урл - нужно подключить JQuery)

Comment: JQuery то сейчас везде есть. И так действительно проще.